# Facing issues on disks in dual boot of windows and ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu-16.04

I am using windows 10 as a dual boot along side with ubuntu 16.04. Whenever I use windows and shutdown it and turn back to ubuntu, I get this error.

```
Error mounting /dev/sda7 at /media/Desmnd/02CE285CCE2849ED: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda7" "/media/Desmnd/02CE285CCE2849ED"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
    Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
    Failed to mount '/dev/sda7': Operation not permitted
    The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
    Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
    read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

I usually fix this error using a command line:

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda7
```

But now, this error is getting more frequent, I want to know, Is it affecting my disk or can it result in corruption of data in my Hard drive?

Thankyou for taking your time for reading such a big question.

Comment: I'd suggest you to shut down your computer from Windows(not restart) after login before switching to Ubuntu to fix this error. This generally happens if you're restarting Windows to Switch to Ubuntu.

Comment: Okay, But for the previous times i have been using it too often. So using "ntfs" command have any risk on corruption of data or failure of Hard Disk?

Comment: When you use that command the only risk it presents is it removes the hibernation file. So generally it should not affect your hard-disk or NTFS file system though it is not recommended to use it often. Best practise would be always shutting down Windows before you use Ubuntu to avoid this issue.